# "President Trump appreciates the outpouring of support for both he and the First Lady" - Should this be he, him or himself?

Tags: personal-pronouns

> "President Trump appreciates the outpouring of support for both he and the First Lady."

Should this be *he*, *him* or *himself*?

Comment: Answers go in the answer box, not the comment box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of hypercorrection, a mistake all too common with pronouns after prepositions in a failed effort to sound more correct.

The preposition "for" takes an object of a preposition, and the object is "him."  It may seem plain or simple because it is.  If you simplify the sentence to "Trump appreciates the outpouring of support for ______," this can help you tell what case the pronoun should be.

"Himself" (as a reflexive pronoun) can be used if "he" or "him" has already been used in the sentence, and is often used instead of "him" in cases like this, again, as hypercorrection.  "He supports himself," for example, but not "*They support himself."

Comment: Trump and Stepien are both affected. Stepien has received many messages of good will,  and Trump appreciates the outpouring of support for ______ him? himself?

Comment: The object of the preposition is *both*. Using *him* after *both*  is just a bit of recent prescriptivism. Historically, *he* following *for both* was by far the more common choice. Ngrams for "for both he and" and "for both him and" cross over around 1938. In 1840, *he* was about four times as common. Today, *him* is about four times as common. So it hardly qualifies as hypercorrection.

Comment: @PhilSweet: That search won't distinguish the construction here from constructions where *for* is being used before a clause, as in "[...], for both he and they were unhappy".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Depends on what he appreciates. *Himself* would imply that he doesn't appreciate the support for anyone else (hm), *him* probably the other person, and *them* for both.

Comment: @PhilSweet Then isn't the pronoun in apposition to both, and also an object of the preposition? At the very least the determiner, well, adverbially of the pronoun?

Comment: I found a couple of different takes on this after posting the comment. Collins treats *both ... and ...* as its own construction and not as a pronoun and appositive. I not sure what's to be gained by doing that, though. And I need to look through more of the ngram data, because that clause structure was doubtless more common in the past.